# Using protected methods in interfaces

Tags: c#, oop, methods, interface, access-modifiers

I wonder whether it is a good idea to use protected members in the interface to create a contract for the derived classes internal logic.

On the one hand, it breaks the encapsulation and leads to possible YAGNI violation (since some of the derived classes might not really need that member), LSP violations (if the derived classes do not fully implement it), tighter coupling etc.

On the other hand, I really want to clearly declare the necessity of some internal logic implementation (which is supposed to be common among all derived classes).

For instance, I want to use the builder pattern in my project. Imagine, I have an interface like this:

```
internal interface IReportBuilder
{
    IReportBuilder BuildHeader();
    IReportBuilder BuildMainBody();
    IReportBuilder BuildFooter();
    AbstractReport GetReport();
}
```

The implementation might be:

```
internal class WorkReportBuilder : IReportBuilder
{
    private AbstractReport _report = new WorkReport(); 

    public IReportBuilder BuildHeader()
    {
        //building the header
        return this;
    }

    public IReportBuilder BuildMainBody()
    {
        //building the main body
        return this;
    }

    public IReportBuilder BuildFooter()
    {
        //building the footer
        return this;
    }

    public AbstractReport GetReport()
    {
        var result = _report;
        Reset();

        return result;
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        _report = new WorkReport();
    }
}
```

Should I just add a method `protected void Reset();` to the interface to make sure that the derived classes do implement resetting?

Comment: Sure having a `Reset` method would force implementations to implement resetting, but it doesn't force them to actually reset in `GetReport`, does it? IMO this sort of contract stuff should just go in your documentation.

Comment: _"I really want to clearly declare the necessity of some internal logic implementation"_ - then it is not an interface. Why would you care about _how_ the author of an implementation of your interface implemented it, as long as it complys with the contract?

Comment: If you do want to enforce some implementation details, but leave some details abstract, how about an abstract class instead of an interface?

Comment: ^^ What Sweeper says. Or maybe a composition of a class and an implementation of an interface?

Comment: Thank you for answers! Could someone explain to me why protected interface members exist then?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "protected interface members".

Comment: I mean protected methods, properties etc of the interface

Comment: All of those are `public`. The interface itself is `internal` in your example. So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Ah, I always forget this is possible, now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#modifiers-in-interfaces - I guess this was introduced in the context of default implementations. A feature that may well have its place - but me no likey... :) And exactly for the reason we see here: it's confusing to beginners (even to some not-so-beginners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interfaces are expected to reflect the behavior of objects that implement it, using `protected` members inside it ruins the whole sense of having an interface.

Regarding your example, you might consider to create an abstract class `ReportBuilder` which implements the `IReportBuilder` interface. Speaking of abstract classes, they can definitely have some internal logic (in your case, representing the `Reset` method). So that your `WorkReportBuilder` derives from the abstract class with private/protected logic you needed.